# Expected value and Cumulative distribution

Tags: probability, expectation

I remember that the expected value of a random variable can be calculated by the cumulative distribution (or 1-CDF). But I don't recall it exactly. Can you please give some hint?

---

**Update:**

Should be $E[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty}Pr\{X\geq x\}dx$.

Does this formula have any special restriction?

Comment: The formula you gave is for strictly positive random variables.

Comment: Hint: Wikipedia: expected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a cts random variable with cdf $F (x)$ and the expectation exists then 
$$\mathsf E(X) ~=~ \int_{0}^{\infty}\big(1-F(x)\big)\operatorname dx\;-\int_{-\infty}^0 F (x)\operatorname dx $$
The case for the discrete can be found by replacing the integral with summation analogously

Comment: What is cts random variable ?